# Добавление фрагмента кода (JS/HTML/CSS) на ноутбуках с сенсорным экраном

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex

Если на ноутбуке с сенсорным экраном нажать кнопку добавления фрагмента кода (JS/HTML/CSS), то появится уведомление с текстом `The snippet editor does not support touch devices.`:

[image: изображение уведомления]

Мне кажется, что

- стоит перевести текст уведомления.
- стоит улучшить систему определения `touch devices`, чтобы на ноутбуках с сенсорным экраном уведомление не появлялось.

Comment: Проблемы богатых... :)

Comment: @NickVolynkin ой ли. Может там chromebook какой-нибудь.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, нет, у меня вообще не дорогой ноутбук)

Comment: Судя по всему, так кнопка отзывается на событие тачскрина. Но только на него. На обычные щелчки (тачпад и мышь) реагирует нормально. Проверил в Windows и Linux. Но ограничение действительно странное.

Comment: @D-side, `touchend` выстреливает. И это печально, сам с этой проблемой сталкиваюсь.

Comment: А вот это окно "подтвердите действие", оно же непосредственно к браузеру относится, да? И просто код и редактор сниппетов это же разные сущности.

Comment: @alexolut, вроде это стандартное окно, появляющееся при [alert](https://learn.javascript.ru/uibasic#alert)'е. Текст «подтвердите действия» относится к браузеру, да. Сущности, конечно, разные, написал так потому что всплывающая подсказка у этой кнопки — `Фрагмент кода на JavaScript/HTML/CSS`.

Comment: Если потыкать, [оно открывается](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303986/snippet-editor-for-touch-devices-can-be-opened-if-you-show-perseverance).