# Редактор сниппетов не работает на телефоне

Tags: дефект, локализация, сниппеты, мобильная-версия

Можно что-то с этим поделать? Начиная с того, что сообщение не переведено, заканчивая тем, что хочется, не то чтобы редактор сниппетов, а хотя бы возможность добавлять шаблон сниппета в ответ.

Сейчас приходится его копировать из другого ответа. То ещё развлечение.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Было](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303986/260198) )=

Comment: @Suvitruf было то было. Вопрос больше про то как с этим дальше жить

Comment: Смириться и простить, разве что.

Comment: Даже перевод не поправить, т.к. в трансификсе этой строки нет =\

Comment: [Связанный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5508/176217). Ну, а по возможности перевода можно смело заводить BR на MSE // cc @Suvitruf